# Problema con widget (no puedo ver el error)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, widget

Estoy haciendo un widget que solo tiene que mostrar una lista de componentes de pc.

Base de datos `articulos`

```
id | nombre          | cateId
-----------------------------
2  | Teclado Genius  | $1499
3  | Disco SSD 128GB | $3599
```

Srcipt

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "URL/include/datos.php");
xhr.onload = function () {
if (xhr.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var template = "";
    template += '<div id="titulo">Titulo</div>';
    json.map(function(item){
        template += item.nombre + " <span>"+ item.cateId + "</span><br>";
        return template;    
        });
        template += '<div id="foot">Pie de pagina<br><a href="#">Articulos</a></div>';  
        document.getElementById("stn_1c3155cceb757fc23f43c7815a1705a3").innerHTML = template;
} else {
    console.log("Error: "+xhr.status);
}
}
xhr.send();
```

HTML

```
<div class="widget" id="stn_1c3155cceb757fc23f43c7815a1705a3"></div>
<script src="http://ux8.com.ar/widget/script.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
```

datos.php

```
<?php
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM articulos");
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $myArr[] = $row;
}

$myJSON = json_encode($myArr);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

En el widget la lista no se ve y no se donde esta el error porque datos.php arroja bien el json.
Agradezco de antemano!

Comment: pero cual seria el problema?

Comment: No se ven los datos que estan en la base de datos

Comment: que quiere decir que no podes ver el error? la llamada se hace correctamente a tu back? los datos vuelven correctamente de tu back?

Comment: Tu código funciona bien con: `var json = [
    {"id": 2, "nombre": "Teclado Genius", cateId: "$1499"},
    {"id": 3, "nombre": "Disco SSD 128GB", "cateId": "$3599"}
];`

Comment: Bueno, un problema menos, pero debe estan en el script de javascript, pero no me dice en que linea

Comment: @gbianchi el archivo `.php` muestra bien los datos json, pero como dije recien, debe estar en `script.js`

Comment: El achivo esta en linea, pueden hacer la prueba insertando el html" `<div class="widget" id="stn_1c3155cceb757fc23f43c7815a1705a3"></div>
<script src="http://ux8.com.ar/widget/script.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>`

Comment: Ahi modifique un dato `URL/` porque los archivos estan dentro de `include` y el error que arroja por consola es este: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON datascript.js:18:19
    onload http://ux8.com.ar/widget/script.js:18`

Comment: Agrega `console.log(xhr.responseText);` antes de crear la variable json, debería aparecer ahí una cadena json que puedes probar en https://jsonlint.com/